# How do I make this wall patch flat?

Tags: repair, walls, hole, patch

I had a hole in the wall, about 10x7x1 inches (length, breadth, depth). I did not know to fix it so I hired someone who brought a [white paste-like compound](https://cmtintas.pt/tintas-texturadas/38-argarugosa.html) to fill the wall. He said it would need to be added as layers over a few days, to give each layer time to dry.

Over a period of a week, I filled the wall with the paste that he had brought. Now, I want to make the filled surface even with the rest of the wall. How do I do this and clean the rest of the wall where this paste has fallen?

This is not drywall, btw.

[image: Wall - please don't judge my poor workmanship]

Comment: What is the "paste" that you put on and what is the wall surface made of?  We need more details about what materials you are working with.  The paste may be drywall compound which is easy to sand off and clean with water...but we do not know that.

Comment: Always remember that the smoother you get it when wet makes any dry work easier.

Comment: @RMDman - it is exactly this - https://cmtintas.pt/tintas-texturadas/38-argarugosa.html

Comment: In the future I recommend *not* hiring this contractor. That looks like a very sloppy job.

Comment: @Matthew - OP says it was DIY. Contractor just supplied the goop…. with no instruction by the looks of it ;)  & no, I wouldn't book him again either to just deliver a standard generic filler product.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a generic ready-mixed '[multipurpose interior filler](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Products/Nails,-Screws+Adhesives/Sealants,-Adhesives+Fillers/Fillers,-Putty+Caulk/Multi-Purpose-Fillers/c/1000020)'. They tend to be quite 'plasticky' once cured, but can be sanded. They have an unfortunate tendency, because of this plasticisation, to clog the grit in sandpaper, meaning you can get through quite a lot even on a small job.

I'd go so far as to say, because of the unfortunate state of the current fill you might need an [orbital sander](https://www.screwfix.com/c/tools/random-orbit-sanders/cat830928) or a very lot of patience if you try to do it manually with a sanding block.

You're also going to have to see how easy the spill is going to come off the wall & skirting below. You really should have protected the area below the job to save all this extra work.
For small spills I have a specially sharpened inflexible triangular filler knife - you could in effect shave the surface where it's spilled down the old good plaster without causing further damage. Something like this might also be OK to get the spill off the wood - or you might just get lucky & it doesn't stick very well to varnished wood…

If you ever have to do a filler job like this in future, then you really need a filler knife, with a broad, flat blade. These are generally flexible, which gives you a nice smooth finish.

[image]

Because this type of filler will slump as well as need working in layers, you fill from the bottom of the hole upwards, which whilst the hole is only part-full, will tend to bunch the filler towards the top of the hole - allowing it to slump slightly as it's drying.
Once you get to the last layer, the flat end of the blade will allow you to finish almost perfectly smooth to the surrounding wall, leaving little to no sanding.

Whilst doing this on tiny areas, you also should use a piece of paper  taped to the wall with masking tape [which won't damage the surface,] just below the working area, meaning any spill falls in it & is easily disposed of. I fold mine into an envelope shape I can keep transferring between holes when either filling or drilling, which you can just throw it straight in the bin afterwards, no fuss.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a better way to remove the stuff on the wood? Like some alcohol solution or something like that which help liquify or loosen the bond?

Comment: If it doesn't just pick off with a fingernail, then it depends what it will dissolve in. It will also very much depend on what your skirting board paint/varnish will dissolve in. If you get very lucky, they will be different substances. I wouldn't just guess, unless you want to risk having to re-coat the wood. You would have to contact the makers of both & see what you can find that dissolves one but not the other. If the filler is still very fresh, dried but not yet fully cured… water might just do it. Once it's fully cured… it may not [the 'plasticky' I mentioned earlier.]

Answer (score 2):

Get some coarse, open grit sandpaper, wrap it around a wooden block, and see if you can get the glop to be flush with the wall.  Note that you need open grit sandpaper or sanding will round over the high spots rather than making flat with the rest of the wall.

Once you've got it flush you can use finer grit paper (not necessarily open grit) to smooth things.

If sandpaper doesn't work you may need to use a paint scraper (https://www.harborfreight.com/2-1-2-half-inch-paint-scraper-with-4-sided-blade-99827.html) to remove the high spots, but this will likely chew up the finish a bit.